# "UnicodeEncodeError",'charmap' codec can't encode characters In Django

Tags: django, unicode

I am working with Django. 
I have a HTML form which collects information from the user,wrote a function which post the value.But when I amtrying to render the value to an URL.(Example:return of the function is like:http://api.test.com?search=topic?title=USA).
But it shows **UnicodeEncodeError** with
**'charmap' codec can't encode characters**
I googled and try to solve from other solution found.Such as using external libraries.

Actually,I want to add user parameter within URL that will be shown in a text area.
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post full trace stack?

Comment: sorry I cant understand you,do you need code or function i coded for that?

Comment: Function call stack from browser when you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Urllib.urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to create get parameters to be added to the url.

I guess, that should solve your problem